# CSS: Trying to achieve a fluid full page grid (no scrolling necessary)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fluid-layout

I'm trying to get the grid on the page below to contain 20 items, full width + full height, and fluid.

So far, I've got the page configured with 20 items, full width, and fluid. Unfortunately, the grid content is being pushed down by the height of the navbar (80px). The only way that I can **eliminate the vertical scrolling** right now is by offsetting the grid section by the negative height of the navbar, specifically:

```
.negative-navbar-offset {
     margin-top: -80px;
}
```

The obvious problem with this method is that the top portion of each item in the first row is being hidden behind the navbar - and a problematic user interface on smaller devices.

The page in question can be viewed here: http://159.203.231.192/about/

So far, I've tried:

1. html, body = 100%
2. grid container at 100vh and 100vw
3. grid container with calc(100% - 80px);

Would greatly appreciate any help/guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just check this code and see if it helps for desktop view

```
header.masthead.masthead-inline {
    margin-bottom: 6em;
}
```

for smaller screens use media queries

Answer (score 0):

This ".tg-grid-slider" div takes inline style (padding:0 2.5px). If we set the padding-top:80px. Then it will help. and set the height through JS. which you have already done.

```
 .tg-grid-slider {
     padding-top:80px;
 }
```